# Class access problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have a class library which is name ClassLib. And that lib has two folders (MedulaClasses and ParserClasses). MedulaClasses has a class which is name SGKDuyurulari.cs. And ParserClasses has a class which is name GeneralParser.cs. I write

```
SGKDuyurulari sd = new SGKDuyurulari()
```

in GeneralParser. but i have a runtime error. but error says just, The type initializer for 'ClassLib.MedulaClasses.SGKDuyurulari' threw an exception. and inner exception is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". 
I dont understand anythig. how can i access class from different folders.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is 'ClassLib.MedulaClasses.KlinikBilgileri' being referenced? You're calling SGKDuyurulari here, does it make a call to that other class?

Comment: We're going to need to see the full stack trace, including inner exception, and all the code that that stack trace references.

Answer (score 1):

The exception you are getting ("type initializer") is associated with a static member. Do you have any static fields or a static constructor in SGKDuyurulari? Something like:

```
private static readonly string someString = CreateSomeString(); // whoops, throws exception at runtime.
```

or:

```
static SGKDuyurulari()
{
    // Do something in here that throws an exception at runtime.
}
```

These are both called the first time anything in your application accesses the type in any way.

Comment: It could be that the constructor expects static fields/properties to have been set prior to instantiation of the class..

SGKDuyurulari.SetMe = "Cakes"
SGKDuyurulari instance = new SGKDuyurulari()

Answer (score 0):

To reference an object in another namespace, just add a using:

```
using ClassLib.MediaClasses;
```

But that isn't the error.  The error is that code in the constructor is throwing an exception for some reason.  Look in the constructor and see what is going on; if you post code, I can help you further.

Comment: public SGKDuyurulari()
        { }

this is my cunstroctur. and i added using.

Comment: Yes, the error signals that some piece of code within SGKDuyurulari's constructor is the cause... Check out the code inside the constructor...  To test, put a breakpoint there and see what's causing it...  Sometimes constructors can hide the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

check the constructor for SGKDuyurulari, is it using an uninitialized object?

[sometimes the folder structure affects the namespace, but if it compiles then that's not the problem]